# Well line cover is leaking in heavy rain. What is the likely fix?

Tags: water, basement, leak, well

My well line comes in at this point below. The water line itself is just the Pex but it’s wrapped in a PVC-like cover. There is water coming in from the PVC cover in heavy rain.

[image]

It’s coming through the bottom of the rusted cover from INSIDE the cover.

I’m not clear on how well lines are designed. Is this cover likely running all the way to the well? Or the other theory is that the cover only runs through the cinder block.

My hope is that the cover only runs through the cinder block and the seal on the exterior where the pipe enters the cinder block is failing.

Another costlier guess is that the pipe runs further and id need to excavate the yard to find the problem.

What do you think?

Comment: Will need to dig down on the outside of the wall and try to seal it up.  If only drips, the bucket is a decent fix for now.  The answers on your other question should help also about having good slope away from the house/wall.  Would not worry about the inside cover, just there for looks.

Comment: So you think the PVC just goes through the wall and not all the way to the well?

Comment: It is possible, but hard to push/pull pipe and wire though and that much tends to get expensive if not needed.  Usually just a short section to make a nice hole/protect from shape edges.

Comment: The black well-water pipe is almost certainly plain old polyethylene, not PEX.

Comment: Good to know thanks!

Comment: Whatever and wherever the leak is, you're going to have to do _some_ amount of digging outside. May as well get started now. This will tell you exactly what you've got going on out there, and will inform the decision on how to proceed. You can share pics of the exterior ([edit] them into your question), and I'm sure you'll get several good suggestions of how to go about fixing the issue.